# AS3: RegEx getting words inbetween square brackets

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a text parser in AS3, that finds words in [square brackets] and replaces them with another set of words. So far, I've managed to create the actual RegEx style, but it keeps spitting out two words-- one in the brackets, and one without. Likewise, I cant manage to make it run continously until the whole sentence has been parsed, and resulter comes out null.

```
public function parseWords(words):String {
        var replacer:String = words;
        var finder:RegExp =  new RegExp("\\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\]");
        var resulter:Object = finder.exec(words);
        trace(resulter[0] == "[Rabbit]");
        //trace (replacer);
        trace (resulter);
        return replacer;
    }
```

Trace results;
true    [Rabbit],Rabbit

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?:

Function:

```
function replaceWords(subject:String, replacementSet:Array):String
{
    var out:String = subject;
    var matches:Array = subject.match(/\[\w+\]/g);

    for(var i:int = 0; i < matches.length; i++)
    {
        out = out.replace(matches[i], replacementSet[i]);
    }

    return out;
}
```

And test:

```
var test:String = "This is [some] text [with] search items.";

trace( replaceWords(test, ["updated", "without"]) );
// This is updated text without search items.
```

Comment: Not entirely. I'm trying to make it so that if something like [Rabbit] shows p, I can call another class to describe the rabbit, so in the string literal being sent I would write "He had a [rabbit]", and in the  parser, it would see [rabbit] and then replace it with pc.getPet();. The last part I can figure out, it's getting the regex to find I can't.

Comment: @AlexMarc So you want to get a list of all the matches first, then send those matches to a component that works out what to do with them, then have that component piece together a new string from the result of that?

Comment: well-- no. While the code runs, it keeps running the exec loop till it returns null. It takes the 0 value of it and replaces it depending on what the component. Though, maybe your way would be far more efficient.

Comment: @AlexMarc Still don't understand exactly what you want to do, sorry about that.

Comment: Basically, all I'm trying to do is create a parser that catches words in [boxes], regardless of the sentence its in. It then replaces the words in boxes with a getFunctions from code. In essence, I'm trying to create a system that when a sentence is written like "[he] had a [rabbit]" the system will go through the whole sentence, find [he], replace it with the code behind it (pc.getGender(), then find [rabbit] and that code (pc.getPet()) and then return the modified string back.
Which could be something like "She had a dog"

Comment: @AlexMarc That's fine, but what acts as the mediator? Like, how is the relationship between the `[text]` and the get function determined?

Comment: I was considering putting an if loop during the the initial while loop of resulter-- so while (resulter != null) { var holder:string = resulter.pop switch (holder) {
case "[rabbit]": 
replacer.replace([rabbit], pc.getpet()

Comment: @AlexMarc So are you going to have a predefined list of tokens and replacements stored somewhere? Otherwise I don't see how you'll know whether to use `.getGender()` or `.getPet()` as you've mentioned, based off the found text. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Well, I was just assuming there was going to be a set amount of things. The textparser was mostly being used on the server side, along with what gets transfered in. It's meant more for convience, so that the system itself would replace [rabbit] rather than having me stop at that point and write " + pc.getRabbit() + ".". It would never be seen to client side, so the tokens that that are in the [text] would be predefined and already known to me.

Comment: Managed to get your code to work. All I had to do was remove the Array requirement and find the if statements in the for loop. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexMarc Great - sorry I became unhelpful pretty quickly there. I'm still having trouble 100% understanding what you're doing. Glad I helped though.